# Meilisearch user specific filtering

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-scout, meilisearch

I have three tables like `users`, `articles` and `user_article`. The `users` table is self-explanatory. In `articles` i have a lots of entries, e.g. 20k. In `user_article` i have entries which article a user has.

If a user goes to the search page he should have a select option with `available` and `unavailable`. If the user selects available, all articles that the logged in user has (from the `user_article` table) should be shown. If the user selects unavailable all other articles and if nothing is selected all articles should be shown.
How can i add a filter / facet to filter the articles by available for the users?

The main idea was to extend the toSearchableArray() with an array that has the information which user has the article, but in documentation is this [information](https://docs.meilisearch.com/reference/features/filtering.html#the-query-language):

> Filtering on nested arrays or objects isn't permitted.

How do you handle such user specific filtering also considering that you can have thousand of users.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you try to find a solution to do many to many relations with MeiliSearch. We are not a relational database so there is no simple solution to that :/

You will have to transform the articles before sending then to meilisearch.

For example something like this ([this can be done in one sql query if you want that but this example will be sub-optimal for clarity](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/173831/convert-right-side-of-join-of-many-to-many-into-array))

```php
$articles = db.execute("SELECT id, title from articles"0:
$users = db.execute(" SELECT id, username from articles"):
$user_article_bind = db.execute("SELECT article_id, user_id from user_article")

foreach ($articles as &$article) {
    // using $article.id, loop over $user_article_bind to find all the user_id that have a connection with the current $article.id
   // with the array of user_ids, loop over $users to transform the id list into username list
    $article["available_user"][] = available_username_array

   // something similar for unavailable_users
}
```

in order to get this structure for the articles, those articles should then be indexed into meilisearch

```json
{
"id": 1,
"title": "my article", 
"available_user": ["john", "marie"],
"unavailable_user": ["Sophia", "michel"]
}
```

Both key should be added because MeiliSearch  cannot do a filter where you can say “give me all articles where “username”  is not present in “available_user”. So you will have to facet filter on both facets.

So, to do that, add both key ["available_user", "unavailable)user" in [attributesForFaceting](https://docs.meilisearch.com/reference/api/attributes_for_faceting.html#attributes-for-faceting) in the settings

and then during search you should do

```
search.(“mysearch”, { facetFilters: [“available_user: michel”])
```

When Michel want all the available articles for him
and

```
search.(“mysearch”, { facetFilters: [“unavailable_user: michel”])
```

When Michel want all the unavailable articles for him.

[original answer here](https://github.com/meilisearch/MeiliSearch/discussions/1408)